# StoryBoard - The agent threw an exception iOS Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am creating a iOS application I want to add ripple effect for a button. So I add `ZFRippleButton.swift` from this github project ([Please refer this link](https://github.com/zoonooz/ZFRippleButton)). Now the ripple effect working fine. Now my problem is my storyboard showing the following error

```
file:///Users/developer/Documents/ios/For%app/extras/deleted%20app/%20qars/klaby%20Kijh/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render instance of ZFRippleButton: The agent threw an exception.
```

But the project is running fine. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the exact issue is. But I solved it.

1. Remove the class for button in storyboard
2. Add again "`ZFRippleButton`" class
3. clean
4. run

Error gone.

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur if a storyboard uses a custom button and the custom button's type is changed. For example, modifying the custom class from a UIButton to a UIView can cause this error.

To resolve, update the UI element used in the storyboard to the same type used in the custom class declaration.